# SVN: Cannot commit 'x' and 'y' as they refer to the same URL?

Tags: eclipse, svn, commit

I'm trying to do a commit on my project and am running into the following error. Pay close attention to the path:

```
Commit failed (details follow):
Cannot commit both
'C:\Development\Project\branches\nextver\project\bin\com\companyname\blah\Foo.java'
and
'C:\Development\Project\branches\nextver\project\src\com\companyname\blah\Foo.java'
as they refer to the same URL
```

How in the world did this happen? I never had my source files in the bin path in Eclipse! What can I do to fix it? Please tell me there's something better than checking it out again and replacing all of the files. I have 191 Java files alone, not to mention resources and Eclipse files.

Comment: Eclipse may not be conveying the correct problem. Can you type `svn status` in the root directory of your project using the command line and edit the question so you can paste in the result?

Comment: I didn't get any errors, just a very long listing of added, deleted and modified files. Nothing interesting. See my answer below for the final, brute force solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to delete and ignore my bin dirs from my local copy. Again. Tortoise SVN seemed to forget that I had done that before and I didn't notice that the bin dirs had crept in, leading to this problem. After resolving several other problems it threw in my path (source trees in conflict, etc.), I managed to get it to commit.

I did first try deleting the .svn folder from the bin dirs, but all that did was cause it to complain that the bin dir was no longer under source control and halt.

Comment: Argh, Tortoise SVN and/or svn just won't ignore the bin folder. More research is needed...

Comment: Set the property `svn:ignore` to include your `bin` directory and make sure that the `bin` directory isn't in your repository either.

Answer (score 6):

I know it's over a year since you posted this, but this may help someone else. I've just gone through the same issue. I eventually traced it back to the project setup on Eclipse. In my case what happened is the build process within eclipse was "building"/copying ALL files in the source folder to the build folder. This caused the .svn directory from the source to be copied to the build folder and this is how Subversion gets mixed up. If you check the paths via RepoBrowser (I am using Tortoise in a Windows environment) the paths point to the correct directories (source and build), but if you run "svn info" from within the directory on your local machine you will find that the source and build directory point to the same URL (hence the message).

Once I realised the problem was within Eclipse and not specific to Subversion it was easy to search for a solution. You need to add "**/.svn/" to the source exclusions in the Java Build Path of the Source tab:

Project --> Properties --> Java Build Path.

Comment: PS. apparantly if you use the Subclipse subversion plugin within eclipse you won't get this problem. I am using Subversion outside of Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Go to `C:\Development\Project\branches\nextver\project\bin\` and delete `.svn` if you see one. And then try committing.

I think somehow stuff in the `src` including the `.svn` got copied to `bin` making both of them seem like they are from the same url in the server. Of course you don't want that. You may want to correct your build settings.

Comment: I think it's possible. And to avoid that in future, setup your build process to exclude `.svn` dirs.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a config file that was shared between two projects but I had updated the file (with the same changes) in both projects.

SVN can't commit as it thinks there are two different sets of changes to be committed to the same file.

So I reverted one of the copies and then I was able to commit.